# Global function or function with no name java for factory pattern

Tags: java, oop, factory-pattern

I want to declare a factory class with some methods and attributes that can be used like this:

```
ClassFactory myObj = MyObj("Class1").method1("input 2");
```

It seems that this is not a valid JAVA statement because JAVA is fully Object oriented and don't let to declare global function. But if there are a mechanism that let define function without name we can define it as a static function and use it as mentioned above.

Is there any way to implement that in JAVA in that manner or any other way?

Comment: A `static` method with a `static` `import` statement?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sotirios Delimanolis for Help:
this is possible with defining the static method and import it statically in every where you want.

```
package factorypakcage;

public class firstFactory{
    public static factoryFunction(String className){
        //switch case for class creation
    }
}
```

Using like this

```
import static factorypakcage.firstFactory.factoryFunction;
...
MyClass MyObj = factoryFunction("Class Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public static method in a class and it can be use globally. For instance a method `public static boolean doesWork() { return true; }` in a public class named `GlobalClass` can be accessed by `GlobalClass.doesWork()` and would return `true`.